# How to get the current Visual Studio Process ID?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

So I run .Net tests and need current MSVS 2022 process id. How one can do such thing in .Net?

Comment: Which one? VS tries to run a lot of stuff in different processes these days. It's better thought of as a collection of processes. E.g. on my machine currently, VS is 54 processes

Comment: Agree with above. If I run my unit tests in VS 2022 I can see in the output window that my tests are run in process testhost.exe not by VS2022

Comment: Adding the version, whilst helpful, doesn't help to address my question. There are lots of processes which, taken together, implement the functionality that is presented as "Visual Studio", the product. Are you seeking the process running the tests? The process which hosts the main UI? Identify the *specific functionality* whose process you're trying to locate (and probably why you think working at the process ID level is necessarily the right one)

Answer (score -3):

Get a reference to the current process and use System.Diagnostics's Process.Id property:

```
int nProcessID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```